# Binded input value does not appear in request

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, alpine.js

I am trying to bind `backAfterSaveStatus` value to hidden input and for some reason then form is submited `backAfterSave` value is null.
After that I go back and submit form again - `backAfterSave` value is 1. Where is the problem?
I tried same thing without `prevent` and `submit()` but it's not working still. Also I had dumped div with `x-text` and code makes hidden input 1 before form submit. What I am doing wrong?

```xml
<form action="<...>" method="post">
    <div x-data="{
        backAfterSaveStatus: '',
        backAfterSave () {
            this.backAfterSaveStatus = '1';
            document.querySelector('form.withBackAfterSave').submit();
        }
    }">
        <input name="backAfterSave" :value="backAfterSaveStatus">
        <div>
            <span>
                <button x-on:click.prevent="backAfterSave()" type="submit">
                    Save & back
                </button>
            </span>
            <span>
                <button type="submit">
                    Save
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want same result as below:

```js
let buttonBackAfterSave = document.getElementById('button-back-after-save');

if (buttonBackAfterSave) {
    buttonBackAfterSave.addEventListener('click',  () => document.getElementById('input-back-after-save').value = 1);
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to reset the value of `backAfterSaveStatus = 0` after the `submit()` call in the `backAfterSave()` method

Comment: I tried it also, but main problem is that first time after form submit value is null.

Comment: @keizah Is this issue specific to alpine/php or can it be solved using JS as well? So to resume, whe the form is submitted, and only after submission, you want to be able to click the button save and back and display 1 inside the input field, correct?

Comment: I reproduced the issue and solved it using the [`$nextTick` magic property](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/#nexttick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just released that I could use simple button with custom name and given value.. No javascript was needed :)

```
<button type="submit" name="back-after-submit" value="1">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the form being submitted "too fast" (the backAfterSaveStatus value isn't done binding to the input). Use $nextTick so Alpine waits until the value is properly changed.

```xml
<form method="post" class="withBackAfterSave">
    @csrf
    <div x-data="{
        backAfterSaveStatus: '',
        backAfterSave () {
            this.backAfterSaveStatus = '1';
            this.$nextTick(() => { document.querySelector('form.withBackAfterSave').submit() });
        }
    }">
        <input name="backAfterSave" x-bind:value="backAfterSaveStatus">
        <div>
            <span>
                <button x-on:click.prevent="backAfterSave()" type="submit">
                    Save & back
                </button>
            </span>
            <span>
                <button type="submit">
                    Save
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I don't use `x-ref` because these buttons are in separate `layouts` file, so I can't move it outside `x-data` range. My final code:

```
<div class="pt-5">
    <div class="flex justify-end" x-data="{
        backAfterSave: 0
    }">
        <input type="hidden" name="backAfterSave" :value="backAfterSave">
        <button type="button"
                class="bg-white py-2 px-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
            {{ __('Cancel') }}
        </button>
        <button type="submit"
                @click.prevent="backAfterSave=1; $nextTick(() => {
                    document.querySelector('form.with-back-after-save').submit()
                })"
                class="ml-3 inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
            {{ __('Save & back') }}
        </button>
        <button type="submit"
                class="ml-3 inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-teal-600 hover:bg-teal-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-teal-500">
            {{ __('Save') }}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```